# scikit-learn LogisticRegression Classify another value

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp

i'm new to python and have to make a natural language processing task.
Using a kaggle dataset a sentiment classify should be implemented using python.
For this i'm using a dataframe and the LogisticRegression, as described in [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-beginners-guide-to-sentiment-analysis-in-python-95e354ea84f6) and everythin works fine.

Now i want to know if it is possible to classify another string which is not in the dataset, so that i can experiment with the classifier interactively.

Is this possible?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to manually run all the preprocessing on youur new data, than predict.

That is:

So first (Data Cleaning) and other functions which you've called which edit the data,
then run the (Create a bag of words) part, and only
Then use the fitted LR model to predict on this (preprocessed) data.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible.

To make this more modular, you can create a function and pass input string to that function for preprocessing. This could reduce the code redundancy. For train data preprocessing also, you can directly pass data to that function.

Once that is done, you need to create Bag of Words for the test sentence.

Then you can use predict function for trained LR model to predict the output.

Thank You.